# Do JNDI lookups keep their connection open - and is this why my load balancing is broken?

Tags: java, jboss, jndi

We have several JBoss servers sitting behind a hardware load balancer using a round robin strategy. All our (JBoss) clients used to sporadically connect and these would be correctly load balanced. However, a new client is sending ~100 queries a minute and these are all being directed to the same server.

I imagine what is happening is that the remote client creates its initial context, does the lookup, and maintains the connection to the JNDI server for a period (about 15s) to save on the overhead of recreating the connection. This means the 2nd, and Nth request go to the same server. We proved this with the following code (Jython using JBoss libraries):

```
def __call__(self):
    p = Properties()
    p[Context.PROVIDER_URL] = "jnp://my.load.balancer:1099"
    p[Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY] = JndiLoginInitialContextFactory.name
    p[Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL] = <redacted>
    p[Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS] = <redacted>

    ctx = InitialContext(p)
    home = ctx.lookup("ejb/ServerNameService")

    ejbQuery = home.create()


    print "Server name: %s", (ejbQuery.getServerName())

    ctx.close()
```

Now, if I call that 100 times within the same JVM (multiple threads) then I always get the same server. If I call that 100 times with new JVMs then I get a mixture.

Is there any way, without using clustering technology, to force JNDI to re-negotiate it's initial connection?

Comment: JNDI is just an API, it says nothing about protocol or connection management. This is specific to the implementation, in this JBoss's JNP protocol.

Comment: Do you have session stickiness enabled? Then its expected behavior.

Comment: @mazaneicha no, it is non-sticky

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe. JNDI is a kind of cache for objects. So if you ask it for the same name several times within the same VM, you always get the same result. That's the correct behavior but you don't like it.

The solution is to register a factory in JNDI instead of the instance itself. That way, the factory can get the information for creating the connections from JNDI but return you a new instance each time it is called (or return one from an internal pool).

The same approach is used with JDBC. Instead of adding JDBC connections to the JNDI cache, a `DataSource` is added - which is a factory for JDBC `java.sql.Connection` instances.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, that's a useful way to look at things - I think this basically comes down to some incorrect assumptions we've made about JBoss.

Comment: Perhaps useful, but very wrong. The JNDI specification does not mandate any specific caching behaviour and making a JNDI lookup twice from the same VM may very well give two different results. The factory "solution" is also used in the EJB specification. The JNDI lookup does indeed give you a factory, on which you have to call create() to get the actual remote stub. In this case, it is however not the solution to your problem, since the factory is also not aware of the load balancer and other cluster nodes.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to tell us what the hardware load balancer is actually "balancing".

Since I can't imagine that a hardware load balancer knows the proprietary JBoss remoting protocol, it is in your case most probably just load balancing the JNDI lookups. This means that all client stubs you obtain from the same InitialContext will eventually go to the same physical server.

If the hardware load balancer should round-robin each request, the remote calls must be made over a protocol supported by the load balancer, e.g. HTTP. This should be supported by JBoss if you configure it properly.

You can of course set up a "real" JBoss cluster as well, letting the JBoss code handling load balancing and fail-over, but the JBoss clustering code is so buggy and fragile, that you most likely will break something else with this approach.

Comment: It's an Level 7 load balancer, you're right. However we don't control the environment - and there isn't time to change the technology, so we're looking for workarounds for the moment.

Many thanks for your response.